# NSString with Japanese Chars

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

In my application i have `NSString` that get String from the web:

```
高瀬 - 虎柄の毘沙門天
```

Now i want to copy this string to a local `NSString` in my Object so i wrote:

```
self.metaDataString = [NSString stringWithString:tempMetaDataString];
```

And now in `metaDataString`  i have :

```
é«ç¬ - èæã®æ¯æ²éå¤©
```

What can make this problem?

i tried this too:

```
self.metaDataString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[tempMetaDataString UTF8String]];
```

How i get `tempMetaDataString`:

```
    NSMutableString *tempMetaDataString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:0];
    //This line i loop over the bytes array size
    [tempMetaDataString appendFormat:@"%c", bytes[i]];
```

And this is the bytes array:

```
    UInt8 bytes[kAQBufSize];
    length = CFReadStreamRead(stream, bytes, kAQBufSize);
```

Comment: How are you getting `tempMetaDataString` in the first place? Isn't it already an NSString?

Comment: How are you printing out `é«ç¬ - èæã®æ¯æ²éå¤©`?

Comment: @trojanfoe I just see in the degugger mode that this is the strings

Comment: The key to this is how the data got converted from the external source (HTTP data) into the original `NSString` object (as mentioned by @cjwirth).  Using `stringWithString` is pointless as is the other code you provide.

Comment: @trojanfoe but `tempMetaDataString` look good but when i copy it ,it's make the problems

Comment: I would assume that the Japanese characters are composed character which mean that adding them one byte at a time breaks the composition.

Comment: That is almost certainly wrong.  You need to know the encoding of the HTTP response and use methods like `stringWithUTF8String` or `stringWithCString:encoding` to get it correctly converted.

Comment: I would suggest not appending it byte by byte. I would probably use `[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:length:encoding:]` instead

Also, I have a hunch that they might be Shift-JIS instead of UTF-8, but don't know for sure.

Comment: I deal with Japanese characters daily.  My advice: Find out the original encoding method.  If you don't see my point, then save the same series of Japanese characters in a file with EUC-JP or Shift-JIS.  And try opening that file with UTF-8 and see what happens.  That's all I can say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line cannot work for multi-byte characters:

```
[tempMetaDataString appendFormat:@"%c", bytes[i]];
```

If you have a multi-byte character, this is going to split it up into individual ASCII characters (as you're seeing).

It's unclear from this code what `bytes` really is. Is the string of a fixed length, or is the string NULL terminated? If it's of a fixed length, then you want (assuming this is UTF8):

```
self.metaDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:bytes
                                               length:kAQBufSize 
                                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

If this is a NULL terminated UTF8 string:

```
self.metaDataString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:bytes];
```

If some other encoding (for example `NSJapaneseEUCStringEncoding` or `NSShiftJISStringEncoding`):

```
self.metaDataString = [NSString stringWithCString:bytes encoding:theEncoding];
```